# Translating ArcGIS field calculator python expressions in to QGIS field calculator python expression?

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, syntax

I'm transitioning to QGIS from ArcGIS.  I'm having trouble getting my python field calculator expressions to work in the QGIS advanced python field calculator.

Here is a screenshot of the working script in ArcGIS:
[image]

Here is what the Advanced Python field calculator window looks like in Q.  I've made some changes based on posted Q&A's that I've seen here and in other places:
[image]

I've gotten some syntax errors that I think I've worked out, but then I'm also getting some "NoneType" errors, which I have no idea what they mean.  I'm assuming the "Global Expression [Optional]" block in QGIS is the same as the optional code block in ArcGIS?

**What does a "NoneType" error mean?**

Below I'll post a snippet of the code.

```
    def getvalue( Exemption_Code, Ag_Value, Appraised_Value, TaxRate_Municipal, Exemption_Local_Homestead, Exemption_Local_O65, Exemption_Local_Disability, Exemption_Vet_3, Exemption_Vet_4 ) :
      if (Exemption_Code == '000') :
        value (Appraised_Value / 100) * TaxRate_Municipal
      elif (Exemption_Code == '002') :
        value (Ag_Value / 100) * TaxRate_Municipal
      elif (Exemption_Code == '004') :
        value 0


    value = getvalue( <Exemption_Code>, <Ag_Value>, <Appraised_Value>, <TaxRate_Municipal>, <Exemption_Local_Homestead>, <Exemption_Local_O65>, <Exemption_Local_Disability>, <Exemption_Vet_3>, <Exemption_Vet_4> )
```

Comment: I notice the layer doesn't appear to be selected in your screenshot? That could  be the problem if the plug-in doesn't check for that.

Comment: Well, the screen shots are staged for the question.  I had been working on it earlier in the day.  I've gotten to where I can run it in the basic field calculator but still no luck so far in the advanced python calculator.  I wonder if I'll beat everybody to it.  If I do I'll post it up.